# Как загружать и работать с файлами на nodejs api + mongoose с патерном async/await?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, multer

Ищу учебный ресурс с примером по загрузке и работе с файлами на nodejs api  + mongoose.
В интернете есть примеры, но те которые я нашел они не полные. Например: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/file-upload-with-multer-in-node--cms-32088

Интересует реализация для ниже пречисленных примеров:

1) при создании поста - загрузить один или нескольких файлов.

2) при редактировании поста - обновить один или несколько файлов привязанных к посту.

3) при редактировании поста - удалить один или несколько файлов

4) при удалении поста удалить один или несколько файлов

5) все должно быть реализовано на патерне async/await

В интернете есть примеры только для 1) пунтка и на базе callback.

А нужны примеры реализации для всех пунктов и с учетом "best practice". Чтобы не просто работало, но и правильно было оформлено.

Comment: Насчет `async/await` советую посмотреть [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771853/how-can-i-promisify-the-mongodb-native-javascript-driver-using-bluebird)

Comment: Или сюда 
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html

Comment: нет. мне нужны конкретные примеры для каждого пункта. вопросы не такие простые как кажуться.  мне нужно работать с файлами как с доп. аттрибутом главного элемента